# Making two planes, separated in space, Indistinguishable to the camera from the front viewpoint

Tags: texturing, materials, modifiers

I am using Blender 2.93. I have two planes. One is a large background plane, and the other is a small flat plane in front of it. In both images, the smaller plane (which lies in front of the larger plane) is indicated by a blue arrow.

[image]

I want both of these planes to be opaque, textured, matte, and look the same. I tried doing this already by applying a Displacement modifier to both planes, but as you can see from the top image, they don't exactly match. The displacement modifier applied to both planes is shown below:

[image]

Ultimately, I would like both planes to have a texture, but when I generate the image from the camera's head-on point of view (shown below), I'd like the front plane to be indistinguishable (or, at least very, very well hidden).

[image]

How can I do this? I've tried simply roughing each surface without the Modifier, but I can't seem to get the level of detail on either plane (detailed, but highly scattering). I have shadows turned off on both planes to reduce the relative visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, what you could do is, at the frame where both the 2 planes are supposed to match and be indistinguishable, unwrap them both with the *Project From View* mode, then in the *Displace* modifier give them the same texture, and in the modifier choose *Coordinates > UV*:

[image]